# C++ string/char* concatenation

Tags: c++, string, char, concatenation

I wrote a small function to accept a "string" and log it.

```
void
IPC::bomb (char * msg) {  /* etc */ }
```

This instance of calling it doesn't compile:

```
bomb( __FUNCTION__": socket() call failed: " + strerror(errno));
```

Diagnostics:

```
./c/IPC.cpp:26: error: expected ')' before string constant
./c/IPC.cpp:26: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'
```

I'm very confused about how to work effectively with quoted literals, std::string, char*, and how const-ness figures into it.  How do I solve the above problem?  And in general, are there some rules of thumb about string concatenation, esp. when mixing char* and strings?

**UPDATE 1**: there may be another issue at work: the C preprocessor shows this expansion:

```
bomb( std::string(__FUNCTION__ ": socket() call failed: ") + strerror((*__errno_location ())));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `IPC::bomb` so that it is `IPC::bomb(const std::string& msg)`, then you could do:

```
bomb(std::string(__FUNCTION__) + ": socket() call failed: " + strerror(errno));
```

and not have any errors.

Here's a complete program to do somehting similar:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>


void func(std::string str)
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    func(std::string(__FUNCTION__) + ":Some string " + strerror(2)); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried that (after inserting a space between `__FUNCTION__` and `": etc.."` but am now getting `./c/IPC.cpp:26: error: expected primary-expression before '(' token
./c/IPC.cpp:26: error: expected ')' before string constant`.  The c preprocessor shows this expansion: `bomb( std::string(__FUNCTION__ ": socket() call failed: ") + strerror((*__errno_location ())));`

Comment: Ok, I've edited and added a complete, small program to try it out with.

Comment: Okay, I guess I didn't notice that you'd wrapped `__FUNCTION__` by itself in std::string(), and *then* concatenated ":somestring".  I was still attempting the `string(__FUNCTION__ ":somestring")` syntax.  By using your approach, it now works (or at least compiles!).  Thanks.

Comment: I changed that as part of adding the demo program, but I don't quite understand why it makes a difference...

Comment: I think I read that `__FUNCTION__` wasn't a macro.  Might that be the reason?

Comment: From http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html: `static const char __func__[] = "function-name";`.  Also, `#  define __func__ __FUNCTION__`

Comment: Ah, that'll explain it.

Answer (score 4):

Your function signature is designed to accept `char*`. However, the value `"string1" + ...` is a `const char*`, because it is a temporary object. Change your function signature to `IPC::bomb(const char* msg)`, and it should be OK.

By the way, you cannot just concatenate two C-style strings using operator+, because it just performs pointer arithmetic. Try using `std::string` instead, casting every string you have to this type.

So, this example could look like

```
void IPC::bomb (const std::string& msg) {  /* etc */ }

bomb(std::string(__FUNCTION__": socket() call failed: ") + 
     std::string(strerror(errno)));
```

if you use strings.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: i could not simply concatenate `__FUNCTION__` "somestring" by placing them together. I was using mingw compiler.

So to be safe, concatenate all three parts together like this:

```
bomb( string(__FUNCTION__) + ": socket() call failed: " + string(strerror(errno)) );
```

Change `void IPC::bomb (char * msg)` into  `void IPC::bomb (const char * msg)` to get rid of the second error so it can accept constant string that are to be protected from any modification.

Comment: Yep.  __FUNCTION__ is actually a *variable* !!! http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html

Comment: `__FUNCTION__` I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot concatenate c-strings (`char*` strings) with the `+` operator (unless you were to write an overloaded operator to do so). You'll have to create a new character string long enough to contain the two that you want to combine and then manually copy them over with `memcpy`, `strncpy` or something similar.